# Setting up Dual Screen Vesa

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, 9.10

I'm wondering if it's possible to set up dual screen using VESA as a driver? and if anybody has a working `xorg.conf` sample that can post. I'm using Ubuntu 9.10

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.  The VESA driver uses the VESA BIOS interface to interact with the video card.  This is an absolutely bare-minimum interface compared to current technology - it dates back to the MSDOS days, before 3D acceleration and when the available VRAM on the graphics card limited your maximum resolution.  Driving two monitors was *not* a priority at this point!

Multiple displays on a single graphics card, and indeed driving multiple graphics cards, requires card-specific knowledge.  As VESA has *no* card-specific knowledge, it can't do it.

That said, we should have appropriate drivers for virtually any piece of graphics hardware you try to run Ubuntu on, and these should support multiple monitors.  If you've got problems with those, that's probably where to look, rather than trying to get VESA to do what you want.